# flutter snackbar animation and swipe

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

what is the entry of animation in flutter SnackBar?

```
ScaffoldMessanger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  animation: /* --- */ 
));
```

I want to change swipe action from default swipe to bottom to swipe right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the swipe direction, you can control the dismissDirection property.

```
SnackBar(dismissDirection:DismissDirection.startToEnd,)
```